# How do you do font-embedding with cross-browser support and no Flash?

Tags: fonts

What's the best solution for embedding non-web fonts into a page without using Flash and still maintaining cross-browser support? Has anyone used any JavaScript libraries for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy answer is one of these services:

http://typekit.com/

http://kernest.com/

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/

They use a combination of Javascript, css and various embeddable font formats.

Answer (score 1):

Cufón seems like a viable alternative, although I have not used it myself.

Site
https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/about

Article
http://www.cameronmoll.com/archives/2009/03/cufon_font_embedding/

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the CSS - and having the appropriate font formats.

Firefox/Gecko likes OTFs, TTFs, and WOFFs
Safari/WebKit/Opera likes OTFs, TTFs
MobileSafari likes SVGs

Javascript is not needed.

Richard Fink is maintaining examples of the most compatible @font-face declarations
http://readableweb.com/mo-bulletproofer-font-face-css-syntax/